# ReactJs this.props.history.push() is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

i'm new with Reactjs and for some reasons i'm working on a small application for learning purpose.

I'm using react-router-dom to navigate between different components.

The idea is when the user click to logout, the App Component should detect the logout event inside the componentWillUpdate() method and then redirect the user to Login Component.

The error is: 
[image]

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from 'react- 
router-dom';
import Login from '../Components/LoginComponent/Login';
import AddNoteForm from "../Components/AddNoteForm";


const AppRouter = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={AddNoteForm} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './Redux/Store/ConfigureStore';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';


const store = configureStore();


const jsx = (
<Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Grid, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Navigation from "./Components/Navigation";
import AddNoteForm from "./Components/AddNoteForm";
import Clock from "./Components/Clock";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AppRoutes from "./Routes/Routes";

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
}
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

if (nextProps.store.user.email === null || nextProps.store.user.email 
== undefined) {
  this.props.history.replace('/login');
}

 }


 render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to this Learing React 
Application.</h1>
    </header>
    <div className="App-intro" >
      <Navigation></Navigation>
      <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
          <AppRoutes />
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return { store };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Package.json

```
    {
      "name": "first-react",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "install": "^0.11.0",
        "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
        "npm": "^6.0.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
        "react-spinner": "^0.2.7",
        "react-spinners": "^0.3.2",
        "react-toastify": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "uuid": "^3.2.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I just read the title but I saw a big mistake here `this.props` is supposed to be read only.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have the `history` in your props, you can use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).
Update the `App.js` file as follows:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

...

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `App` component is not being wrapped with `BrowserRouter`. You need to wrap it somewhat like this:

```
const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={AddNoteForm} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
    </Switch>
);

const jsx = (
<Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider> 
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
           <AppRouter />
           <Route component={App} />
         </div>
       <BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</Provider>
);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it in a better way, should I change Routes.js file like you mentioned ?

Comment: @BenFarhatSouhaib First thing is that your `App` component must be a child of `BrowserRouter` to use `history`. Second thing - you need to pass `history` prop somehow. You can use `withRouter` HOC or use `Route` component which will pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md, you can just render component in `App.js`

```
 componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

if (nextProps.store.user.email === null || nextProps.store.user.email 
== undefined) {
  return <Redirect to="/login" />
}
```